# Annular segment in 3D

Tags: graphics3d, regions

I would like to plot a segment of a circular annulus in three dimensions with constant thickness (like a thick washer, but through some limited ranges of angle).  This shows the shape:

```
RegionPlot3D[
 (5 < Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 6 && 5 < z < 6 && 0 < ArcTan[x, y] < .5) ,
 {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10},
 Mesh -> None,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Red]]
```

[image: Annular segment]

However, this requires an extremely high number of PlotPoints (which will be undesirable in my full figure, containing many dozens of such shapes).  Moreover I would like to retain the thin edge lines and impose `Opacity[]`, colors, and so forth, as can be applied in all Graphics3D primitives such as `Cylinder[]`.

I could work with Regions, such as this start:

```
Region[
 RegionDifference[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1],
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1/2]]]
```

[image: Difference of cylinders]

but here too I won't get the thin edge lines and opportunity to adjust the overall opacity and color as I seek.

In two dimensions, there is a perfect graphics element:

```
Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Orange, Annulus[{0, 0}, {1/2, 1}, {0, .3}]}]
```

[image: Orange annulus segment]

What I'm seeking would be called `Annulus3D`.  In the absence of such a 3D primitive, how shall I plot what I seek?

---

Just to show the final result (using the linked code from @kglr, below):

[image: Munsell-like color solid]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`RegionProduct`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionProduct.html):

```
rp = RegionProduct[Annulus[{0, 0}, {1/2, 1}, {0, .3}], Line[{{0}, {1/10}}]];

Region[rp]
```

[image]

An alternative approach: Modify the trick in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154091/125) to add a location parameter:

```
ClearAll[annulus3D]
annulus3D[ctr_, {θ1_, θ2_}, {r1_, r2_}, {z1_, z2_}] := 
   Translate[ 
     ChartElementData["CylindricalSector3D"][{{θ1, θ2}, {r1, r2}, {z1, z2}}, 1], 
     ctr]
```

***Example:***

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Gray}], 
  Opacity[.5, Red], annulus3D[{1, 1, .5}, {Pi/3, 2 Pi/3}, {.5, 1}, {0, .6}], 
  Opacity[.5, Blue], annulus3D[{0, 0, 0}, {Pi/4, 3 Pi/2}, {.25, 1.5}, {.5, .75}]}, 
 Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but cannot the the edge lines, color, and opacity I seek.  How would I get this style `Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5],EdgeForm[Blue],Red,Cylinder[]}]` on my region wedge?

Comment: does [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154091/125) work for you needs?

Comment: Hah... yes!  Thanks.  I searched but hadn't found that.  For your (continuing) good works:  $\checkmark$.