# Lighting/Mesh problem after GeometricTransform

Tags: graphics3d, mesh, rendering

This is probably a silly question but...

**Context**

I have gathered from this site Functions to draw sets of concentric [3D rings](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153544/1089)

as follows:

```
annulus3D[c_?VectorQ, {r1_, r2_}, h_?Positive] /; 0 < r1 < r2 := 
 BSplineSurface[
  Map[TranslationTransform[c], 
   Map[Function[pt, 
       Append[#1 pt, #2]], {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 
        0}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}}] & @@@ {{r2, h}, {r1, h}, {r1, 
      0}, {r2, 0}}, {2}], SplineClosed -> True, 
  SplineDegree -> {1, 2}, 
  SplineKnots -> {{0, 0, 1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/2, 
     1/2, 3/4, 1, 1, 1}}, 
  SplineWeights -> 
   Outer[Times, ConstantArray[1, 4], {1, 1/2, 1/2, 1, 1/2, 1/2, 1}]]
ring3D[orientation_?VectorQ, radius_?NumberQ, width_?NumberQ, 
  height_?NumberQ] := 
 GeometricTransformation[
  annulus3D[{0, 0, 0}, {radius, radius + width}, height], 
  RotationMatrix[Pi/4, orientation]]
```

so that

```
ring3D[{0, 0, 1/2}, 3, 3, 0.1]
```

produces

[image]

But as soon as I wrap it with a `Graphics3D`, it displays a mesh and is **very** slow

```
Graphics3D[ring3D[{0, 0, 1/2}, 3, 3, 0.1]]
```

[image]

**Question**

> How can I simply recover the rotated object so that I can superimpose them
> and still have *smoth* surfaces and fast rendering? (*No mesh*)

E.g. Not this:

```
Graphics3D[{ring3D[{0, 0, 1/2}, 3, 3, 0.1], 
            ring3D[{0, 1/2, 1/2}, 3, 3, 0.1]}]
```

[image]

It might be that the solution involves something else than `GeometricTransformation` ?

I use Mathematica 12.3 on MacOS.

Note that on Wolfram Cloud the code fails differently: only
the first annulus is shown when aiming to display two; so something is wrong with the 3D bounding box.

Comment: No mesh problem on iOS Wolfram Cloud (kernel 12.3.0 Linux). Lighting looks a little odd to me, like the surface normals are botched. Not sure about the speed due to internet layer between the app and kernel, but re-renders after rotating quickly. Have you tried `EdgeForm[]` — looks like after the conversion region -> graphics, the edges of the polygons are being drawn. It might be a bug (probably is, imo, at this point).

Comment: @MichaelE2 If I use J.M.'s code `annulus3D2[c_?VectorQ, {r1_, r2_}, h_?Positive] /; 0 < r1 < r2 := 
 RegionProduct[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Annulus[c, {r1, r2}]], 
  MeshRegion[{{0}, {h}}, Line[{1, 2}]]]` I get much improved performance but still a mesh

Comment: No problem on my laptop ("12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)") except when rotating the graphics in the Front End, the shading gets darker toward the center. What version are you using?

Comment: No problem with *Mathematica* 12.3.1 on Windows 10 x64, except that the second code displays only one ring.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I can confirm your result.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov should I label this question as a bug then?

Comment: @chris Probably not, because your specific problem isn't reproduced. Other buggy behavior is found, but not what you describe in the question. I suggest reporting to the support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround for my specific problem,  but I am still interested in other answers which may address the original problem (Most of the credit goes to J.M. of course).

The idea is to extract the `MeshCoordinates` and `MeshCells` by hand.

```
annulus3D[c_?VectorQ, {r1_, r2_}, h_?Positive] /; 0 < r1 < r2 := 
 Module[{tt, pts, polys}, 
  tt = RegionProduct[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Annulus[c, {r1, r2}]], 
    MeshRegion[{{0}, {h}}, Line[{1, 2}]]];
  {pts, polys} = {MeshCoordinates[tt], MeshCells[tt, 2]};
  {EdgeForm[None], GraphicsComplex[pts, polys]}
  ]
ring3D[orientation_?VectorQ, radius_?NumberQ, width_?NumberQ, 
  height_?NumberQ] := 
 GeometricTransformation[
  annulus3D[{0, 0}, {radius, radius + width}, height], 
  RotationMatrix[Pi/4, orientation]]
```

which allows me to produce

```
Graphics3D@ring3D[{0, 0, 1}, 3, 3, 1/2]
```

[image]

And eventually

[image]